# CentOS vs Debian on memory usage?

Tags: centos, debian

Just curious as I'm thinking of switching to CentOS.

Comment: I am downvoting this question since you clearly have not done any research regarding how linux works and what the difference between these distros is.

Comment: What I meant was the bare bones of the operating systems. As in, how much RAM does each used on a minimal installation. I do know differences; Debian uses dpkg while CentOS inherited RHEL's system of package installation/updating (yum). CentOS is also aimed more at enterprises.

Comment: well, then you need to edit your question, apparently you want to compare the memory usage of a minimal installation of each distro.

Answer (score 2):

They are both Linux systems which means same kernel and consequently same memory management subsystem unless there is a special patch applied :)

Comment: I suppose... Debian seems to be using more than my dedicated RAM (VPS) which is worrying me...

Comment: how are you checking for the amount of memory used?

Comment: I checked in SolusVM and by doing `top` via SSH. `top` says `Mem:    524288k total,   226512k used,   297776k free,        0k buffers
`

Comment: without also looking at the amount of cached memory, you have an incomplete picture

Comment: but the fact that it has so much memory free is odd.  its a sign that either processes using a lot of memory were just shut down, or that the box hasn't been up long enough to fill the cache.  typically you SHOULD see almost no free memory, since free memory should get used as disk cache

Comment: @Fike: You may not be able to easily compare two Linux system unless you have exactly same hardware/same running applications, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The amount of used memory is going to depend on the installed and running daemons or other resident programs. Since almost all of these can be shut off on both CentOS and Debian, the base systems should be almost identical in terms of memory usage.

If you're asking about the "default installation", I have built extremely compact Debian systems with almost nothing running; as a consequence these consume very little memory when they first boot up. On CentOS (in my limited experience) there is a lot more installed by default, thus more memory will be consumed when they are first booted. However as mentioned above, since almost everything can be shut down and removed, this is easily customizable.